# Unable to add 10th table to PDF using ITEXT in Java

Tags: java, itext

After adding 9th table to pdf. I tried to add 10th table but I'm unable to add it
[image]

I can able to add only below
[image]

```
col101 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", ArialFont.ARIAL10));
col101.setColspan(10);
col101.setRowspan(6);
col101.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table_10.addCell(col101);

col102 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", ArialFont.ARIAL10));
col102.setColspan(10);
col102.setRowspan(6);
col102.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table_10.addCell(col102);
```

But I need as below. But when I code as below it is not working.

```
col101 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", ArialFont.ARIAL10));
col101.setColspan(21);
col101.setRowspan(6);
col101.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table_10.addCell(col101);
```

Comment: How is `table_10` defined? And what do you mean by `it is not working`?

Comment: When I create a table then it is not showing any col (or) rowspan

Comment: *"When I create a table then it is not showing any col (or) rowspan"* - and what *does it show* instead? By the way, it makes no sense to set a row span for a cell that spans all columns. Row span only makes sense if there are columns left with all those rows needed.

Comment: Initially, I set it to empty, when I ran it I will add some value to those cells, but with an empty string. I could not able to create any table.